# Monodevelop reformat strings

Tags: formatting, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop when I select the "Format" menu to clean up the code spacing it converts this code:

```
string a =@"
sdfsdf
sdfsdf
sdfsdf";
```

into  single line

```
string a = @"sdfsdf\n\sdfsdf\n\sdfsdf\n\n";
```

Is there a way to tell the formatter to ignore strings on multiple lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in MonoDevelop. It has been reported and fixed in r150648 by Mike Krüger, so it should show up in the next release of MonoDevelop.

StackOverflow is for programming questions, when you face a bug, please file a bug as explained [here](http://monodevelop.com/Developers), so we don't lose track of it.